# Access denied error in ASP.NET development server

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008

I just added the following lines to an existing (working) project:

```
if (File.Exists(c_szInvoiceFolder + szAttachmentFile))
    File.Delete(c_szInvoiceFolder + szAttachmentFile);
if (File.Exists(c_szApp_DataFolder + szTemplateFile))
   File.Copy(c_szApp_DataFolder + szTemplateFile, c_szInvoiceFolder + szAttachmentFile);
```

When the code runs the first time, the file is copied as expected.

However, when the code is re-run, I get "Access to the path ... is denied" on the delete line.

According to all the documentation I can find, the ASP.NET development server should run as the logged on user. That seems to not be the case here as I can delete the files myself.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

NOTE: this is happening on my laptop when running in the VS Dev environment.

ANOTHER NOTE: Why would I have permission to CREATE and NOT DELETE?

BTW, I have tried to fix this by granting EVERYONE Full Access to the directory. No help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The original file was ReadOnly so the copy was ReadOnly. Cleared the ReadOnly flag from the original and all works ok.